# Finite groups and topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, graph-theory

Can we connect topological spaces with groups as:

For topological space $X$ take biective homomorfisms $\phi: X\to X$, then divide such homomorphisms on classes of equivalency $\phi_1 \equiv\phi_2$ if exists continious homotopy between them. Then easy to see that these classes form group $G_X$ with operation as composition.

Is this correct? If we look on every finite graph $Gr$ as on topological space (edges are segments in $\mathbb{R}^N$, for large $N$), then is $G_{Gr}=Aut(Gr)$?

Comment: Why do you say "finite groups" in the title? Your $G_X$ will not be finite in general.

Comment: Yes, but for finite graphs it is finite. Question: for wich topological spaces this group is finite?

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer to say "finite graphs" in the title.

Comment: For topological spaces more interesting to define groups wich are finite for finite graphs

Comment: But the body of your question doesn't mention finite groups $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: Many people like finite groups more than others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with your construction. If $X$ is homeomorphic to a circle, then $G_X \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, but if $Gr$ is an $n$-gon, $Aut(Gr)$ is the dihedral group of order $2n$, so your conjecture doesn't hold in that case. Maybe it would hold under some extra assumption, e.g., no vertices of valency 2.

Answer (score 0):

If $Gr$ is connected and every vertex has valence $\ge 3$ then this is true: in this case it is a theorem of Serre, in his book "Trees", that no pair of distinct automorphisms of $Gr$ are homotopic to each other.